# Mark duplicate row by last date

Tags: sql, sql-server

A Have records:
visit_id |patient_id|doctor_id|date
[image]

Last column- repeat_visit. 
How is the request to find the last visit a patient's repeated visit to this doctor?

Comment: Put some effort in asking the question. You have mentioned 4 columns but the image has more than 6 columns. Also post the sample data and expected result as table in text format.

Comment: I am edit qwestion.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking to return the record that a patient last visited a specific doctor, and you will filter by both patient and doctor. If so, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT *
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date DESC PARTITION BY patient_id, doctor_id) rn
FROM PatientsTable
) a
WHERE rn = 1
AND patient_id = 1234
AND doctor_id = 5678
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to see it is patient's first visit or repeated visit. If it is true, you can use this query.

```
SELECT V.visit_id, V.patient_id, V.doctor_id, V.dd, V.h, V.mins, 
    ( CASE WHEN VST.visit_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) repeat_visit
FROM 
    visit_table V
        OUTER APPLY( SELECT top 1 V1.visit_id FROM visit_table V1 WHERE V.visit_id > V1.visit_id
        AND  V.patient_id =  V1.patient_id ) AS VST
```